# Molar heat capacity of gas defined by relation $p=kV$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

we have this problem where relation between Pressure($p$) , Volume($V$) is defined by relation $$p=kV$$ where $k$ is a constant and we have to find the molar heat capacity of the gas.
Note:Ideal gas eqation is still valid
so Here's what i thought $$PV=nRT$$ $$=kV^2=nRT$$ and $$\Delta Q=mC_{x}\Delta T$$
now how we have to somehow relate the two eqation to get out $C_{x}$ how to get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine the two equation the easiest way is probably taking a "pseudo-derivative" of the equation of status:

$2kV\Delta V = n R\Delta T$

And then substitute $\Delta T$. I don't find the resulting expression for $C_x$ very illuminating, however the initial hypothesis is pretty weird.